# conditional test to regex conversion (Phone numbers)

Tags: jquery, regex

I checked the other regex phone formats however mine is little different.  I wrote down code to format phone numbers while the user typing the number by using keyup function (jQuery).  I used some very elementary regex patterns, however I think that all formatting can be done by regex.

- the phone format will be like `(312) 317 72 84`
- Total number of chars is 15
- while user typing the code adds "(" and " " to code
- the phone number should not be started with `0`

Current problem:
     Since it adds " " whitespace to code however when user press backspace it deletes the whitespace and adds new one. Backspace keyup should be treated separately

My current code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/kWd4k/

Comment: The fact that your phone number is in a slightly different format does not merit a separate question. Take a while to understand the previous approaches and you can easily adapt them.

Comment: Yes, i know that this one is not a unique question at all. However, i am totally stranger to regex patterns. It could be very difficult for me to form a pattern which exactly do what i want

Comment: I thought your question is not about regexen at all, isn't it about the backspace key behavior?

Comment: I think that all those messy if / if else conditionals can be removed. But not sure if regex can handle all

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in this condition:

```
if(e.keyCode!=8){ //since you're using jQuery, you can use e.which instead
...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNYCv/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object to the function which handles the keyup event and check for backspace using `e.which`

```
$("input.phone").keyup(function(e) { 
    if(e.which!=8){
    ....
    }
});
```